# Data scaling in magento 2 like integration nosql to load product data from nosql

Tags: magento2, php, database, pagespeed

How we can integrate nosql with magento to load pages data faster than mysql

Comment: what are you talking about???

Comment: You can find adapter in github mage2nosql